# I want to write to a file by using ofstream but it gives me nothing

Tags: c++, file-writing

I have created three directories with `_mkdir()`, and I want to create a text file in the last one, but it gives me nothing.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int t;
    string path, subpath;
    path = "D:";
    subpath = "d";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        path = path + "\\" + subpath;
        t=_mkdir(path.c_str());
        if (t)
            cout << "create directory\n";
        else
            cout << "unable to create directory\n";
    }
    fstream file;
    file.open("filetest.txt", ios::out||ios::in);
    file << "haha";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `fstream file; file.open("file text.txt", ios::out | ios::in);` to `fstream file("file text.txt", ios::out | ios::in);`.

Comment: what is the meaning of "gives me nothing"? The file is not created? The file is empy?

Comment: `ios::out||ios::in` - typo, it should be `ios::out|ios::in`. But then, that's the default value, so you can omit that completely.

Comment: If [`_mkdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkdir-wmkdir?view=msvc-160) fails once, it will likely fail three times. Besides, you use the result of `_mkdir`  wrong, it returns `0` (false) if it *succeeds*. Also, why create the directory if you're not going to use it? You never change to that directory, instead the file is created in the working directory of the process. Oh and lastly `ios::out||ios::in` is using the *logical* or operator, and the result will be `1`. You should use the *bitwise* or operator `|` (single pipe character).

Comment: The **title** mentions `ofstream` (which is what you need), but the code uses `fstream`.

Comment: You probably want to create the file in the deepest directory, so you should do: `file.open(path + "/filetest.txt", ios::out);`

Comment: On another note, you never check if the file opened successfully, you just assume it does and write to it anyway. And remember that C++ streams are *buffered* which means the contents might not be written until you either close the file or explicitly flush the buffer.

Comment: thank you for your caring @PeteBecker , now I have modified ny code how can I change it here?

Comment: If you use C++17 or later, your entire loop can be replaced with a single call to [`std::filesystem::create_directories()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), eg: `std::string path = "D:\\d\\d\\d"; if (!std::filesystem::create_directories(path)) { std::cout << "unable to create directory\n"; } else { cout << "create directory\n"; std::fstream file(path + "\\filetest.txt"); ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a file in the working directory instead of the last created directory.
Replace

```
file.open("filetest.txt", ios::out||ios::in);
```

with

```
path = path + "\\filetest.txt";
file.open(path.c_str(), ios::out|ios::in);
```

Comment: Paths can be `std::string` objects since the C++11 standard, no need for the `c_str()` call.

Comment: Who knows what standard OP uses. OP may be using vc++6 because of stdafx.h.

Comment: @S.M. thank you so much ,I used your code and it works just fine